# Inherit model doesn't override field definition in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I've created a module in Odoo 10 with the following code to inherit the `product.product` model and override the existing `standard_price` field definition to set it as a computed field:

```
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    standard_price = fields.Float(
        'Cost', company_dependent=True,
        digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price'),
        groups="base.group_user",
        compute='_compute_set_standard_price')

    def _compute_set_standard_price(self):
        .....
        # calculation for the value
        .....
        self.standard_price = 121 #this value is an example
```

The `standard_price` would be set to 121 because I've overridden the field definition to a computed field but the `standard_price` field is set to 0 and doesn't trigger the compute method. This code in Odoo v8 works fine.

What's the way to override an existing field definition in an inherited model?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use decorator `api.depends`.

```
 @api.depends('field_1', 'field_2')
 def _compute_set_standard_price(self):
        .....
        # calculation for the value
        .....
        self.standard_price = 121 #this value is an example
```

when odoo create a record or update a record it will check for computed field that depends on the field that are passed in the dictionary to recompute the computed field according to the new value.
without a trigger odoo will not compute the value